# Overwrite the text file using jsp

Tags: java, jsp, web

I am trying to overwrite a text file which contains 6 lines of data by inserting 6 different lines of data.

Here is my form.

```
<form method="POST" action="write.jsp">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name1"  size="20" /><br> 
    Price: <input type="text" name="price"  size="20" /><br> 
    Due time: <input type="text" name="DueTime"  size="20" /><br> 
    Location: <input type="text" name="Location"  size="20" /><br> 
    Photo Url: <input type="text" name="url"   size="20" /><br> 
    Description: <input type="text" name="desc"  size="20" /><br> 
    <input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="window.close()"/>
</form>
```

After user clicks on submit, it will go to write.jsp, which is shown below.

```
String name = request.getParameter("name1");
String price = request.getParameter("price");
String DueTime = request.getParameter("DueTime");
String Location = request.getParameter("Location");
String url = request.getParameter("url");
String desc = request.getParameter("desc");

String paths="somepath/hotel1.txt"; 

FileWriter filewriter = new FileWriter(paths, true);

filewriter.write(name + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
filewriter.write(price + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
filewriter.write(DueTime + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
filewriter.write(Location + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
filewriter.write(url + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
filewriter.write(desc + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
filewriter.close();
```

But somehow it does work, can anyone help me to fix this?

Comment: Why write files from .jsp? Doesn't sound like an MVC architecture  to me.

Comment: I agree with comment above. But lets say you have to do it. why request.getParameter() is in different case. Also, do you have this whole thing in scriptlet ?

Comment: Sry, the cases for request.getParameter() is a careless mistake. I am doing school assignment, which requires me to use jsp to complete the tasks. Anyway, I think I have alr solved the problem, thank your for your concerns!

Comment: You need a new school!